# how to make NOT clickable email address on mobile (android)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to prevent opening mail clients when address email being clicked?
I got address email inside a div

```
<div class='run_function' >mymail@gmail.com </div>
```

The div is linked to javascript function on the desktop it works fine but on the mobile, it keeps opening Gmail. I tried to wrap it a  tags without href attribute but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about clicking on mobile try adding read only attribute. I don't see your JS script but if this disabled the clink on desktop too then do a [media rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and use classes to show one div to desktop users without this read only and one with too mobile users.

```html
<div class='run_function' readonly >mymail@gmail.com </div>
```

Or try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  run_function {
    *your code here*
  }
}
```

Or:

```
<div class='run_function'>mymail<span>@</span>gmail.com </div>
```

Also read more: [how to disable links](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/).

Comment: When I added readonly it works the same. It triggers the function on desktop but on mobile still opens the gmail app

Comment: Try adding your run_function class in @media rule that will trigger the class only to desktop users.

Comment: Try adding monkey in span tags. That confuses the app. See my last edit up.